# Is there a way to generate a combo list of string characters by accessing the dictionary?

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

key_map = {'1': "'-", '2': 'abc', '3': 'def',
               '4': 'ghi', '5': 'jkl', '6': 'mno',
               '7': 'pqrs', '8': 'tuv', '9': 'wxyz'}

Generate a list of all 3-character prefixes that can be
        generated from the beginning key presses.

> > > pt = PText()
> > >       pt.add('234')
> > >       [prefix for prefix in pt.possible_prefixes()]

```
    ['adg', 'adh', 'adi', 'aeg', 'aeh', 'aei', 'afg', 'afh', 'afi', 'bdg', 'bdh', 'bdi', 'beg', 'beh', 'bei', 'bfg', 'bfh', 'bfi', 'cdg', 'cdh', 'cdi', 'ceg', 'ceh', 'cei', 'cfg', 'cfh', 'cfi']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I had some trouble reading your question at first, I believe you're looking for a function that will take a string containing keys of the dictionary and find all combinations of characters from the strings under those keys.

Although we could use for loops or list comprehensions to implement this ourselves, what you are looking for is a form of [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product). Python's standard library can already do this, using `itertools.product`. It takes any number of iterables as an argument and returns all combinations of single elements taken from those iterables.

Thus, your `possible_prefixes(keys)` could look like

```py
import itertools
def possible_prefixes(keys):
    return ["".join(res) for res in itertools.product(*(key_map[key] for key in keys))]
```

The `*()` is a [generator comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) that converts each key into its corresponding value, and then expands it so that each entry is a seperate argument of `itertools.product`. Thus, if we filled in `keys = '234'` it would expand to `itertools.product('abc', 'def', ghi')`, which gives the required result. The `"".join(res) for res in` is a list comprehension that we need because `itertools.product` actually returns tuples, and you need a list of strings.